# Error while loading model weights in pytorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, pytorch, torchvision

My model was in a .pth file and for loading the model i wrote this code.

```
model = torch.jit.load('/content/drive/MyDrive/fod.pth')
torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'weights.pt')
u2net = U2NETP()
u2net.eval()
u2net.load_state_dict(torch.load('/content/weights.pt'), strict = False)
```

U2NETP is the network architecture, but the problem here is that I am getting an error which goes like this

```
_IncompatibleKeys(missing_keys=['stage1.rebnconvin.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage1.rebnconvin.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage1.rebnconv1.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage1.rebnconv1.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage1.rebnconv2.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage1.rebnconv2.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage1.rebnconv3.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage1.rebnconv3.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage1.rebnconv4.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage1.rebnconv4.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage1.rebnconv5.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage1.rebnconv5.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage1.rebnconv6.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage1.rebnconv6.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage1.rebnconv7.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage1.rebnconv7.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage1.rebnconv6d.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage1.rebnconv6d.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage1.rebnconv5d.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage1.rebnconv5d.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage1.rebnconv4d.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage1.rebnconv4d.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage1.rebnconv3d.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage1.rebnconv3d.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage1.rebnconv2d.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage1.rebnconv2d.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage1.rebnconv1d.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage1.rebnconv1d.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage2.rebnconvin.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage2.rebnconvin.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage2.rebnconv1.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage2.rebnconv1.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage2.rebnconv2.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage2.rebnconv2.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage2.rebnconv3.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage2.rebnconv3.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage2.rebnconv4.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage2.rebnconv4.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage2.rebnconv5.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage2.rebnconv5.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage2.rebnconv6.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage2.rebnconv6.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage2.rebnconv5d.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage2.rebnconv5d.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage2.rebnconv4d.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage2.rebnconv4d.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage2.rebnconv3d.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage2.rebnconv3d.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage2.rebnconv2d.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage2.rebnconv2d.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage2.rebnconv1d.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage2.rebnconv1d.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage3.rebnconvin.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage3.rebnconvin.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage3.rebnconv1.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage3.rebnconv1.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage3.rebnconv2.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage3.rebnconv2.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage3.rebnconv3.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage3.rebnconv3.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage3.rebnconv4.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage3.rebnconv4.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage3.rebnconv5.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage3.rebnconv5.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage3.rebnconv4d.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage3.rebnconv4d.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage3.rebnconv3d.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage3.rebnconv3d.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage3.rebnconv2d.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage3.rebnconv2d.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage3.rebnconv1d.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage3.rebnconv1d.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage4.rebnconvin.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage4.rebnconvin.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage4.rebnconv1.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage4.rebnconv1.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage4.rebnconv2.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage4.rebnconv2.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage4.rebnconv3.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage4.rebnconv3.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage4.rebnconv4.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage4.rebnconv4.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage4.rebnconv3d.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage4.rebnconv3d.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage4.rebnconv2d.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage4.rebnconv2d.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage4.rebnconv1d.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage4.rebnconv1d.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage5.rebnconvin.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage5.rebnconvin.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage5.rebnconv1.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage5.rebnconv1.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage5.rebnconv2.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage5.rebnconv2.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage5.rebnconv3.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage5.rebnconv3.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage5.rebnconv4.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage5.rebnconv4.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage5.rebnconv3d.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage5.rebnconv3d.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage5.rebnconv2d.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage5.rebnconv2d.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage5.rebnconv1d.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage5.rebnconv1d.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage6.rebnconvin.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage6.rebnconvin.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage6.rebnconv1.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage6.rebnconv1.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage6.rebnconv2.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage6.rebnconv2.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage6.rebnconv3.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage6.rebnconv3.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage6.rebnconv4.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage6.rebnconv4.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage6.rebnconv3d.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage6.rebnconv3d.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage6.rebnconv2d.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage6.rebnconv2d.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage6.rebnconv1d.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage6.rebnconv1d.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage5d.rebnconvin.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage5d.rebnconvin.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage5d.rebnconv1.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage5d.rebnconv1.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage5d.rebnconv2.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage5d.rebnconv2.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage5d.rebnconv3.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage5d.rebnconv3.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage5d.rebnconv4.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage5d.rebnconv4.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage5d.rebnconv3d.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage5d.rebnconv3d.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage5d.rebnconv2d.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage5d.rebnconv2d.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage5d.rebnconv1d.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage5d.rebnconv1d.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage4d.rebnconvin.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage4d.rebnconvin.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage4d.rebnconv1.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage4d.rebnconv1.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage4d.rebnconv2.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage4d.rebnconv2.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage4d.rebnconv3.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage4d.rebnconv3.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage4d.rebnconv4.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage4d.rebnconv4.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage4d.rebnconv3d.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage4d.rebnconv3d.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage4d.rebnconv2d.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage4d.rebnconv2d.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage4d.rebnconv1d.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage4d.rebnconv1d.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage3d.rebnconvin.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage3d.rebnconvin.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage3d.rebnconv1.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage3d.rebnconv1.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage3d.rebnconv2.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage3d.rebnconv2.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage3d.rebnconv3.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage3d.rebnconv3.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage3d.rebnconv4.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage3d.rebnconv4.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage3d.rebnconv5.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage3d.rebnconv5.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage3d.rebnconv4d.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage3d.rebnconv4d.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage3d.rebnconv3d.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage3d.rebnconv3d.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage3d.rebnconv2d.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage3d.rebnconv2d.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage3d.rebnconv1d.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage3d.rebnconv1d.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage2d.rebnconvin.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage2d.rebnconvin.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage2d.rebnconv1.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage2d.rebnconv1.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage2d.rebnconv2.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage2d.rebnconv2.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage2d.rebnconv3.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage2d.rebnconv3.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage2d.rebnconv4.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage2d.rebnconv4.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage2d.rebnconv5.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage2d.rebnconv5.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage2d.rebnconv6.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage2d.rebnconv6.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage2d.rebnconv5d.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage2d.rebnconv5d.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage2d.rebnconv4d.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage2d.rebnconv4d.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage2d.rebnconv3d.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage2d.rebnconv3d.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage2d.rebnconv2d.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage2d.rebnconv2d.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage2d.rebnconv1d.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage2d.rebnconv1d.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage1d.rebnconvin.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage1d.rebnconvin.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage1d.rebnconv1.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage1d.rebnconv1.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage1d.rebnconv2.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage1d.rebnconv2.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage1d.rebnconv3.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage1d.rebnconv3.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage1d.rebnconv4.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage1d.rebnconv4.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage1d.rebnconv5.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage1d.rebnconv5.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage1d.rebnconv6.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage1d.rebnconv6.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage1d.rebnconv7.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage1d.rebnconv7.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage1d.rebnconv6d.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage1d.rebnconv6d.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage1d.rebnconv5d.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage1d.rebnconv5d.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage1d.rebnconv4d.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage1d.rebnconv4d.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage1d.rebnconv3d.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage1d.rebnconv3d.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage1d.rebnconv2d.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage1d.rebnconv2d.bn_s1.running_var', 'stage1d.rebnconv1d.bn_s1.running_mean', 'stage1d.rebnconv1d.bn_s1.running_var'], unexpected_keys=[])
```

[image: The output after printing the keys inside weight.pt file]

```
for param_tensor in sd:
    print(param_tensor, "\t", model.state_dict()[param_tensor].size())
```

I used this code for printing the weights. Seems like it contains weights and bias keys but not running mean/ variance

Comment: Are you sure the `weights.pt` is the correct weight for `U2NETP`?

Comment: This is almost as if there's nothing inside `weights.pt`.

Comment: Try printing the keys inside weights.pt.

Comment: for param_tensor in sd:
    print(param_tensor, "\t", model.state_dict()[param_tensor].size())                                                          I ran this code for checking the files inside weight.pt

Comment: I have added the screenshot of the keys in weighs.pt file

Comment: The ```weights.pt``` is extracted from a ```.pth``` file. And i loaded it before and it was working fine but now its not